# Android Studio Update 3.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Just updated to 3.2.1 Android Studio

[image]

And i get the following errors when i try to run the app

[image]

[image]

Before the update everything was fine.

Comment: So show us the 13 errors.

Comment: @Onik See updated photos

Comment: Looks like the errors are in generated folders. Maybe something are cached. Can you try cleaning and building, removing the generated folders, or as a last step invalidating the cache and restarting (not this step would get rid of any un-commmited work, so make sure to commit before running)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

Build->Clean Project
Then
File->Invalidate Caches/Restart...->Invalidate and restart

If this doesn't work then Try Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files

Still not working then its time to get brutal.

File->Close Project.

**Backup the project.**

Get rid of the build/ directory (if you have one at the top and/or module levels) and the .gradle/ directory along with .idea/, build/, and .gradle/ of a project copy, then import it again.

And if this doesn't work.

Delete the same files again and also the .iml file from the project folder. Then, import the project using "Import  Project(Gradle, Eclipse ATD..." from the welcome dialog that appeared when you chose Close Project earlier.

Don't forget to cross your finger while doing all of this.

Comment: do you have git version control for this project? I'm asking because it sounds to me like the upgrade messed up some files. Sorry, I can't help much more.