# Android resource compilation failed after update to 3.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing an app on Android Studio, everything was going fine but when I updated android studio to latest 3.2.1. Whenever I rebuild it, it started throwing error like:

```
'Cannot resolve symbol r'

Android resource compilation failed

Output:  C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2387: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

Command: C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\95f7c8f43460b8291b9636dd6edf99d6\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

values.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Error comes up in this line of `values.xml`:

```
<item name="textviewprofile" type="id">Logout</item>
```

I tried every was possible to way fix error in `values.xml`, but no solution, whenever I make changes to the values.xml file, the default one comes up again after rebuild. Any help would be appreciated

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52913178/1571605) - might help

Comment: Did you check this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/52076491/6891563

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944600/4255978

Comment: i tried all of them, still cant get it work

Answer (score 0):

For id type item no value is required. Just remove the value. Use this

```
<item name="textviewprofile" type="id"/>
```

instead of

```
<item name="textviewprofile" type="id">Logout</item>
```

Comment: I know it, but the changes does not reflect after rebuild. It shows the default setting everytime

Comment: After change remove build folder and clean project and run again.